# How to achieve connecting points from different series in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

So this is pretty much what I'm trying to achieve:
[image: chart]

Each bar would be a series, and each serie would have associated a point within the metrics.

The issue here is that I cannot figure out how to join those dots with the line, apparently for being separated series.

Here we have a similar example, but only with one series:

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-dual-axes

Hope anyone can help out here.

Many thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: I do not understand the problem. You have a separated line series which can customised however you want. Is it the problem how to have dotted lines instead of solid?

Comment: Explain what you mean by "connect". Show us your actual chart that you are working with rather than a generic Highcharts demo chart.